# How do I call an Objective C function?

Tags: objective-c

How to call a function in Objective C? For example:

I define the function in header (.h file):

```
-(void)abc
```

and implement this function in implementation file (.m file):

```
-(void)abc
{
//.....
///....
}
```

Now how would I call this function from where I need it?

Answer (score 26):

To call this method from within the same class you would call :

```
[self abc];
```

To call from another class, assuming you have a reference to an instance of that class you would call :

```
[instance abc];
```

If you have parameters in the method, for the first parameter you would declare it as (assuming it is a string) :

```
- (void) abc : (NSString *)param1;
```

And call it as :

```
[self abc:@"Yoop"];
```

All following parameters must be given a name. So for example if there were two parameters you would declare it as :

```
- (void) abc : (NSString *)param1 paramName2:(NSString *)param2;
```

This would be called like :

```
[self abc:@"Yoop" paramName2:@"Woop"];
```

It does take a little getting used to to start with, but there is method to the madness! In Objective-C terminology you arent really calling the method, you are passing a message. This is a good blog post describing the differences : [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/objective-c-niche-why-it-survives-in.html)

I discuss this here: [What's with the square brackets (calling methods)](http://fungushumungus.blogspot.com/2009/02/whats-with-square-brackets-calling.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a method on some class. If the class is called Foo, it might be something like this:

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo abc];
```

Answer (score 0):

it's too easy just write

```
[self function];
```